# Could someone check my Lebesgue measure dilation proof?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The Theorem is as follows: If $\delta > 0$ and $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is measurable then $\delta E$ is measurable and $m(\delta E) = \delta^dm(E)$.

My proof is as follows:

Since $E$ is measurable, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an open set $O$ where $E \subseteq O$ such that $m_*(O - E) \leq \epsilon$. For $\delta E$ we can choose $\delta O$. We now have $\delta E \subseteq \delta O$ and $m_*(\delta O - \delta E) \leq \epsilon$ so $\delta E$ is measurable (I think I may have skipped over some reasoning here.)

Next to show $m(\delta E) = \delta^dm(E)$ we can write $E$ as a countable union of cubes $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty Q_j$ where each $Q_j \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is a cube. So this means we can form a covering of $\delta E$ by elongating the $d$ sides of each $Q_j$ by a factor of $\delta$. This would mean
$$\delta E \subseteq \bigcup_{j = 1}^\infty \delta^dQ_j$$
Since $E$ is measurable we can now perform the following:
\begin{align*}
m(\delta E) &= \inf \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |\delta Q_j|\\
&= \delta^d\inf \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |Q_j|\\
&= \delta^d m(E)
\end{align*}
Could I please check if my proof is correct and that I haven't missed any steps? I'm still new to measure theory so I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not completely valid, but the ideas are good.
You should probably first prove that $m_*(\delta G) = \delta^dm_*(G)$ for any set $G$ so that you can then say that $m_*(\delta O - \delta E) \leq \delta^m\epsilon$ (in your proof of measurability of $\delta E$).

Your proof of the equality $m(\delta E) = \delta^dm(E)$ is not completely clear to me either.
First you decompose $E$ into cubes, which is not the way I would go. As I said we need to prove  $m_*(\delta G) = \delta^dm_*(G)$ for any set $G$. So I would rather say that $m_*(G) = \inf \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |Q_j|$ where the infimum is taken over all countable coverings of $G$ with cubes.
Now you say that $m_*(\delta E) = \inf \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |\delta Q_j|$, but it is not clear to me. Think about it - what is the infimum even taken over assuming the cubes are a decomposition of $E$ (like in your original solution)? Now assuming that we are considering all coverings of $E$ instead of decompositions it makes more sense and is indeed true (but we have to prove it).
So now we will prove $m_*(\delta G) = \inf \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |\delta Q_j|$. The "elongated" covering is derived from some covering of $G$; a priori we don't know if every covering of $\delta G$ is derived in this way. So all we can really say is that $$m_*(\delta G) = \inf \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |P_j| \leq \inf \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |\delta Q_j| = \delta^d\inf \sum_{j = 1}^\infty |Q_j|
= \delta^d m_*(G)$$ where the infimum with $P_j$ is taken over all countable coverings of $\delta G$ with cubes, and the infima with $Q_j$ are taken over all countable coverings of $G$ with cubes (notice the difference!). The inequality holds because an infimum over a bigger family of coverings is not bigger than an infimum over a smaller family of coverings.
What I mean is: $\delta Q_i$ is a covering of $\delta G$, but a priori we don't know if every covering $P_i$ of $\delta G$ is necessarly of the form $\delta Q_i$ for some covering $Q_i$ of $G$. Thus all coverings of $\delta G$ form a (not necessarly strictly) bigger family (in the sense of inclusion) than the "elongated" coverings derived from coverings of $G$.
Thus $m_*(\delta G) \leq \delta ^d m_*(G)$. Now do the same for $\delta^{-1}$ in place of $\delta$ and $\delta G$ in place of $G$ to get the $\geq$ inequality.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: I did not downvote, but for decomposing $E$ into cubes, should I have made it clear it was meant to be a countable covering of cubes? Furthermore, do I open a new question so I can check the amended version of my proof as well as the $\geq$ inequality?

Comment: I also would like to know if showing that $E$ and $\delta E$ are measurable is sufficient to use $m$ instead of $m_*$ throughout the proof.

Comment: Actually, upon further investigation, your answer doesn't make much sense. I initially upvoted, but now I want to downvote. You reference "this equality" a lot - which one are you talking about? Are you talking about $m_*(\delta G) = \delta^d m_*(G)$ or $m_*(\delta E) = \delta^d m_*(E)$? Please write it as "the equality <equality>" for example. Also, what makes the family of $P_j$ "smaller than or equal to" the family of $Q_j$? Finally, how does the equality $m_*(\delta G) = \delta^d m_*(G)$ in any way helpful to prove the measurability of $\delta E$, and what can I really use to prove it?

Comment: @Kookie I'll edit my answer accordingly to make it clearer.

Comment: @Kookie in your proof of measurability of $\delta E$ you say that $m_*(\delta O - \delta E) \leq \epsilon$. That's not generally true. But  $m_*(\delta O - \delta E) \leq \delta^d \epsilon$ is true (and can be proven from the fact that $m_*(\delta X) = \delta^d m_*(X)$ for any set $X$) and it implies measurability of $E$.